# Pytest: create incremental fixture value with argument

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

Okay so I have this fixture:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def dummy_name():
    def func(name="Dummy Name"):
        num = 2
        while True:
            yield name
            if num > 2:
                tags = name.rsplit("_", 1)
                name = f"{tags[0]}_{num}"
            else:
                name += f"_{num}"
            num += 1

    return func

@pytest.fixture
def dummy_admin_name(dummy_name):
    return dummy_name(name="Dummy Admin")
```

I can use it like this:

```py
def some_function(dummy_admin_name):
     print(next(dummy_admin_name))
     print(next(dummy_admin_name))
     print(next(dummy_admin_name))
```

Which returns:

```py
Dummy Admin
Dummy Admin_2
Dummy Admin_3
```

But the problem is I have to create that secondary fixture all the time for different strings,  because calling the the base `dummy_name` fixture doesn't work:

```py
def some_function(dummy_name):
     print(next(dummy_name(name="Dummy Admin")))
     print(next(dummy_name(name="Dummy Admin")))
     print(next(dummy_name(name="Dummy Admin")))
```

Which returns:

```py
Dummy Admin
Dummy Admin
Dummy Admin
```

Clearly because adding the argument three times resets the `name` value every time.

How could I make that input persistent for future calls without a new fixture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you wrote, you cannot call the fixture multiple times, as it will re-create
the function each time. However, you could just create the callable before using it:

```py
def test_something(dummy_name):
    dummy_admin = dummy_name(name="Dummy Admin")
    print(next(dummy_admin))
    print(next(dummy_admin))
    print(next(dummy_admin))
    dummy_user = dummy_name(name="Dummy User")
    print(next(dummy_user))
    print(next(dummy_user))
```

which prints:

```
Dummy Admin
Dummy Admin_2
Dummy Admin_3
Dummy User
Dummy User_2
```